# Is there an equivalent to yarn audit --groups "dependencies" in npm?

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I am wondering if there is an equivalent of `yarn audit --groups "dependencies"` in npm. I checked npm doc but did not find answer to it.

Comment: `npm audit --production`? See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-audit.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, that's might be the answer.